# Apple: "Code singing is required ..."

Tags: certificate

Is a developer certificate required if I only want to deploy an app to my iPhone / iPad ? Now when I try do build I get

```
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'
```

Should I get a certificate or is there something else I can do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. To build on the iPhone, you need to join iOS Developer Program for $99 a year. Once you join, you can set up your certificate and provision profile.

You can use the simulator without the iOS Developer Program.